# Bootstrap, table-stripped class for only specified columns

Tags: bootstrap-table

I just want to apply table-stripped class to my 3 colums. Totally I have 5 colums, but 3 of them needs to be stripped. Any idea for that?

For example, I only want to apply table stripped to selected area below:

[image: Example image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override first td element with `style="background-color: white;"`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color: white;">John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color: white;">July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```